# Algorithm For Determining Overlapping Geographic Areas

Tags: php, dictionary, geospatial

I have the latitude and longitude for a point for which I then compute circle using a radius to give a range.  I also have latitude and longitude bounds of a geographical region (in this case a state).  I'm trying to find out if any area of the circle intersects the any area region.

Basically the end result I'm looking for is if a point (geocoded address) is within x miles of any state it will return that state.

I'm sure there's some sort of algorithm to find this, but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: How do you represent your states?

Comment: Data for the states is coming from Google's Geocode API.  So for Illinois, the data would come from this URL.  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=IL,%20United%20States&sensor=false

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
a = sin²(Δlat/2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin²(Δlong/2)
c = 2*atan2(√a, √(1−a))
d = R*c
```

JavaScript:

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1)*Math.PI / 180;
var dLon = (lon2-lon1)*Math.PI / 180;
var lat1 = lat1*Math.PI / 180;
var lat2 = lat2*Math.PI / 180;

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

This will give you the great-circle distance between any two points. The rest depends on how you represent the states.

Comment: That is some crazy formula. I never thought about the curvature of the earth and would have approximated it to be flat, but this is definitely awesome. +1 for you.

Comment: The states I retrieve as approximate rectangular bounds, it does not have to be 100% accurate, but google's geo coding API returns the bounds as:

<southwest>
<lat>36.9702980</lat>
<lng>-91.5130789</lng>
</southwest>

<northeast>
<lat>42.5083379</lat>
<lng>-87.0199349</lng>
</northeast>

I don't believe the Haversine will work in this case because I am not trying to determine the distance between the points, rather if *any* point within the given radius falls within the rectangular bounds.

Comment: @Josh: You could test distance of the point to each point of the rectangle, if it fails for each you could test if the point lies within the rectangle (those steps can be swapped) if both failed you calculate the points that have the given distance from your point and lie exactly north, south, west and east from your point and test if they lie inside the rectangle. If all of those tests failed the state is not within the range of your point. If one did not fail the state is within the range.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree

This is an excellent starting point for any kind of 2-d spatial relationship kinda stuff.

Comment: The Earth is not 2D euclidean space so quad trees would not be appropriate for this.

Answer (score 0):

If your post would be tagged with Java and not with PHP, I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel but just use JTS (Java Topology Suite), create one geometry and call the method

```
public boolean intersects(Geometry g)
```

I don't know much about PHP, so I can't tell you if there is a comparable library for PHP.

Where are the geometries from? You could also try to call some underlying functions, for example a database call, if your geometries are stored in a database like PostGIS

Answer (score -2):

If you're trying to see if a single point is within a circle, you can use Pythagoras' theoy for. In the below code, pass the centre_x, centre_y and radius of your circle, and then the x,y for the point you're evaluating.

```
def in_circle(centre_x, centre_y, radius, x, y):
    square_dist = (centre_x - x) ** 2 + (centre_y - y) ** 2
    return square_dist <= radius ** 2
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the curvature of the Earth.